# ¿Cómo puedo aumentar a que me calcule los números de 2 en 2?

Tags: javascript

```
function rotando(){
    let valor1;
    let resultado;
    valor1 = prompt('Ingresa el valor');
    while(valor1<20){
        resultado = valor1 +=2;
        console.log(`El numero es ${resultado}`);  
    } 
}
rotando();
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error con este código?

Comment: Comenta un poco que pasa

Comment: Ya está respondido, prompt manda una cadena, lo que sumado a 2, da una cadena ingresada mas un 2... 22, 32, 42, etc... hay que castear el ingreso para que sea evaluado como numero

Answer (score 3):

Se puede hacer algo como esto;

```js
function rotando(){
  var valor = parseInt(prompt('Valor'));
  if (isNaN(valor)) {
    console.warn('El valor ingresado no es un número.');
    return;
  }
  var size = (20-valor)/2;
  var result = Array.from({length: size}).map((_, i) => valor+i*2);
  console.log(result);
}
rotando();
```

Tambien puedes imprimir cada valor

```js
  result.forEach(console.log);
```

Comment: Si escribo *texto* en el `prompt` tu programa falla. A tomar en cuenta eso. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras agregué la validación, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
function rotando(){
    let resultado;
    let valor1 = Number(window.prompt("Ingresa el Valor", ""));
    while(valor1<20){
        resultado = valor1+=2;
        console.log(`El numero es ${resultado}`);  
    } 
}
rotando();
```

Resulta que `promtp` manda una cadena, por lo que es correcto castearlo a número.

Comment: Funciono, segun viendo el codigo, lo que hacia falta era convertir a numero lo que estaba intentando pasar por teclado , correcto = es decir convertirlo a entero

Comment: Si por que como dije en la respuesta, prompt manda una cadena

Comment: Entonces lo que hacia el codigo, era tomar lo ingresado, y ponerle un 2 al lado, no sumarlos debidamente como numeros. Si pruebas con el primer codigo tuyo, veras que da igual que ingreses, terminara en 2. Ingresas 2, es 22, ingresas 3, es 32.. etc

Comment: excelente, si , ahora me acorde, que en js todo lo que le pasamos lo lee como si fuera una cadena o string y que hay que convertirlo en caso de que queramos que no los muestre como numero....

Comment: Si te sirve todo bien, recuerda marcarlo como respuesta, cualquier duda, consulta aca mismo ;)

Comment: Excelente hermano...

Comment: Marcalo como respuesta XD sino la gente sigue llegando a revisar el problema

Comment: Si escribo *texto* en el `prompt` tu programa falla. A tomar en cuenta eso. Saludos

Comment: Eso es por que es una tarea simplemente, si tuviese un ingreso correcto, no sería por prompt, ni menos solo js